# std::ofstream weird behavior when writing integers on byte border from 256

Tags: c++, c++11, ofstream

Tring to create a binary file format, but weird behaviour.

```
    std::ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open (PATH, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary |
    std::ios_base::app);
    unsigned long long int timer3 = 255;
    outputFile <<reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&timer3);
    timer3 = 256;
    outputFile <<reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&timer3);
    timer3 = 257;
    outputFile <<reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&timer3);
    timer3 = 258;
    outputFile <<reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&timer3);
```

Binary output file only contains (in hex)
        FF 01 01 02 01

FF- 255

01 01- 257

02 01 -258

why does it blatantly disregard 256 (and 512, 1024..)?

whats the best for writing integer by integer to binary?

Comment: Never use `operator <<` and `operator >>` on binary files.  They are for formatted input/output (text mode)

Comment: You treat `&timer3` as a pointer to a NUL-terminated string. It just so happens that the value 256 on a little-endian machine has zero low-order byte (and so looks like an empty string), while 255, 257 and 258 do not. Your four calls write 1, 0, 2 and 2 bytes, correspondingly.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects to meaningful values rather than using their default constructors and immediately changing them. That is, change `std::ofstream outputFile; outputFile.open(whatever);` to `std::ofstream outputFile(whatever);`. And if the code that isn't in this snippet calls `outputFile.close()`, that's not necessary. The destructor will close the file.

Comment: any alternatives to writing integer by integer in binary to file?

Comment: Expanding on an above comment, `reinterpret_cast` tells the compiler, "Ignore all your type checking and do something that according to the rules is a bad idea. I know what I am doing. You can use this variable the way I describe." When you are wrong, all bets on the behaviour of the program are off. Use `reinterpret_cast` with caution.

Comment: Side note: According to the Strict Aliasing Rule, you can view any object through a pointer to `char`, so what's been done is legal. Whether it makes sense logically or not is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @user4581301 There is nothing wrong with `reinterpret_cast`ing to alias to `char*`, and indeed that is not the problem here.

Comment: @NathanOliver binary/text axis is orthogonal to formatted/unformatted axis.

Comment: Why are you storing binary data? Text is portable and human readable. Binary data makes sense if you cannot afford text because of storage or performance overhead.  But for three timers?

Comment: "why ?" you said it yourself "storage or performance overhead"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the formatted insertion operator `<<` and giving it a `const char*`, you're telling the stream that you're giving it a C-string, i.e. a null-terminated sequence of bytes to be interpreted as characters.

But this is not true.

Indeed, any `long long` value with a "null" component (any byte set to zero) will terminate that formatted insertion.

How else would the `<<` know when to stop?

You should use `outputFile.write(...)` instead, as this is how "raw" bytes are directly inserted into a stream.

```
outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&timer3), sizeof(timer3));
```

Note that, unless you write some indicator into your file that tells readers in what *endianness* the values were written, you will never be able to unambiguously read them out again. (However, for a naive, non-portable application this may not be a consideration.)

Comment: i am gonna allow hex formatting .. so endianess is will be left for the user to decide. thanx alot

Comment: @DisplayName You still need to record what endianness the values were written in (unless you know for sure this file will only ever be used on the same computer). How you end up formatting the result on screen is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

When writing `char*` to a file using stream operator (`<<`) it stops on first terminating NULL (= 0).

255 in Little-Endian will be translated to **0xff 0 0 0**  therefore  it writes only the **0xff**

256 will be translated to **0 0x01 0**, therefore it considered an empty string since it starting by 0.

257 will be translated to **0x01 0x01 0**, so it will be printed fine.

Any number that it first byte is 0 (such as 512, 768, 1024 all are multiplies of 256) won't be printed with your method (on Little Endian machines such as Windows and Linux) since the first byte is 0.

Comment: You should offer up a solution like "Use [`std::ostream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to write binary data rather than the formatted text operators when writing binary data." to complete the answer. Right now it's left dangling.

Comment: any alternatives to writing integer by integer in binary to file?

Comment: Put the integers into an array and `outputFile.write` the array.

Comment: `outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&timer3), sizeof(timer3) )`is the alternative.